# Equation numbering gone wrong

Tags: equations, numbering, subequations

There are three issues that I would like to fix which are probably interlinked, but don't know how (have tried a couple of things):

1) Force the equation numbering of equation 3.7 to move to the right-hand side of the the lower equation (underneath the updownarrow, so it looks like the numbering of equation 3.8.
2) Avoid compressing the size of the lower equation
3) Avoid italic font of equation 3.8

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

    \begin{equation}
     \frac{c_r(6\sigma+3)+4\sigma^2(\sigma-2P_c+1)-2P_c+1}{(2\sigma+1)^2} = 0 \\
         \center\Updownarrow \\
     P_c^* = \frac{4\sigma^2+4\sigma+1+4\sigma^3+6c_r\sigma+3c_r}{2(1+4\sigma)}\center
    \label{3.7}
    \end{equation}
    \vspace{-3cm}

 The original paper produces the following result:

    \begin{equation}
     P_c^* = \frac{4\sigma^2+4\sigma+1}{2(1+4\sigma)}
    \label{3.8}
    \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please post the a working document, not just fragments

Comment: you must have had multiple errors from that fragment? you can not use `\\ ` or `\center` in `equation`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Done.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Yes, I do get three errors in total. For some reason, I can't see the explanations on them when I hover the mouse over.

Comment: Using `\label{3.7}` is not really recommended. Please the `alignat` environment` for something like this

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: What would you recommend instead?

Comment: tex does not attempt to make sensible typeset output after an error, it just recovers enough to process the document to check for more errors.  you can never use `\center` in math mode, for multi-line math display do not use `equation` use an environment from `amsmath`

Comment: @Saud: Something easy to remember. What's the purpose of `\labels` if you name them like the equation number (which can change, most likely). Use `\label{myimportantresult}` or something like this

Comment: you possibly want to try using the `gathered` environment inside the equation numbered 3.7; that will allow you to separate lines by `\\ ` and center all the lines with only a single equation number.  as @DavidCarlisle says, `\\ ` is not allowed inside `equation`; that is meant for either one-line displays, or displays that have a grouping environment that treats them as a unit.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Haven't really used the gathered environment before, but  after just having read about it makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot break lines in `equation`. Use a  `gathered` environment within equation. The label will be typeset *between* the equation lines, unless you load `amsmath` with the `tbtags` option. If you want the label to appear on the last line, you can use the `gather` environment, and `\notag` on the first two lines:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{3}
\begin{equation}
  \begin{gathered}
    \frac{c_r(6\sigma+3)+4\sigma²(\sigma-2P_c+1)-2P_c+1}{(2\sigma+1)²} = 0 \\
    \Updownarrow \\
    P_c^* = \frac{4\sigma²+4\sigma+1+4\sigma³+6c_r\sigma+3c_r}{2(1+4σ)}
  \end{gathered}
\end{equation}

\begin{gather}
  \notag \frac{c_r(6\sigma+3)+4\sigma²(\sigma-2P_c+1)-2P_c+1}{(2\sigma+1)²} = 0 \\
  \notag \Updownarrow \\
  P_c^* = \frac{4\sigma²+4\sigma+1+4\sigma³+6c_r\sigma+3c_r}{2(1+4σ)}
  \label{3.7bis}
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

[image]